# How set min/maxScale (or Resolution) at Openlayers map

Tags: javascript

How set min/maxScale (or Resolution) at Openlayers map

I tried:

> **a. In my module :**
>
> ```
> function myoladd_openlayers_map_alter(&$map = array()) {
>     $map['maxScale'] => 14000000;   }
> ```
>
> **b. In `openlayers.module`**
>
> ```
> set $map['maxScale']=14000000; in openlayers_build_map
> ```
>
> **c. In `js\openlayers.js`**
>
> ```
> set options.maxScale
> ```

also, I have tried different values of Scale, Resolution.